# MongoDB query two collections with sort orders

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Example: Let’s assume the following collections. ThrashMetalDocumentsCollection and SpeedMetalDocumentsCollection, both collections having the same HeavyMetalRecordDocument structure as shown below. How do I query and return ALL of the records in both collections and sort them by releaseDate (oldest first) and rating (high to low)? Thanks! \m/ \m/

```
static async Task getAllRecords()
{
    var builder = Builders<HeavyMetalRecordDocument>.Filter;
    //var filter;

    using (var cursor = await ThrashMetalDocumentsCollection.Find()
    .Sort(Builders<HeavyMetalRecordDocument>.Sort.Ascending(x => x.rating))
    .ToCursorAsync()) 
    {
        while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
        {
            foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)
            {
                //Do Something…
            }
        }
    }
}

public class HeavyMetalRecordDocument
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public String artist { get; set; }
    public String title { get; set; }
    public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; } // 1-10
}
```

Comment: Just look at mongodb $lookup operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is not a relational database, and as such, it cannot perform joins (which is what you are trying to accomplish). You probably want to think more about the structure of your database. Without knowing any more about what you are trying to do, I would suggest putting all types of albums into a single collection - putting in an additional field indicating the genre of the album.

Comment: I will make some minor adjustments and limit the scope to one collection. Thanks!